# Actionscript 3.0 Creating Boundaries with Arrays

Tags: actionscript

Currently I'm working on a project recreating a mario level, my issue is that when I do not hard code the bottomLimit (the floor, currently set to 400) Mario will eventually just fall through.

Another thing I can't quite figure out is how I can move my invisible block that creates the floor boundary to accomodate the flooring. The level chosen is the Fortress level of Super Mario Brothers 3, if that helps picture what I'm trying to do with it.

There are a couple .as files to my code, I will put my troublesome file in along with my collision code.

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;


public class FortressMap extends MovieClip
{
    private var _mario:SmallMario;
    private var vx:Number = 0;
    private var vy:Number = 0;
    private var _ceiling:Array = new Array();
    private var _floor:Array = new Array();
    public const accy:Number = 0.20;
    public const termv:Number = 15;
    public var onGround:Boolean;
    public var bottomLimit:Number;

    public function FortressMap()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

        _mario = new SmallMario();
        addChild(_mario);
        _mario.x = 50;
        _mario.y = 400;

        //Creating the blocks for the floor
        createFloor(16, 416);

        //Creating the blocks for the ceiling
        createCeiling(16, 352);
}

    private function createFloor(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):void
    {
        var floor:Floor = new Floor();
        addChild(floor);
        floor.x = xPos;
        floor.y = yPos;
        floor.height = 16;
        _floor.push(floor);
        floor.visible = false;
    }

    private function createCeiling(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):void
    {
        var ceiling:Ceiling = new Ceiling();
        addChild(ceiling);
        ceiling.x = xPos;
        ceiling.y = yPos;
        ceiling.height = 16;
        _ceiling.push(ceiling);
        ceiling.visible = false;
    }

    private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeStageHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
    }

    private function frameHandler(event:Event):void
    {

        _mario.x +=  vx;
        _mario.y +=  vy;


        if (_mario.x < 16)
        {
            _mario.x = 16;
        }

        vy +=  accy;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < _ceiling.length; ++i)
        {
            Collision.block(_mario, _ceiling[i]);
        }
        for (var j:int = 0; j < _floor.length; ++j)
        {
            Collision.block(_mario, _floor[j]);
        }

        bottomLimit = 400;

        if(_mario.y >= bottomLimit)
        {
            _mario.y = bottomLimit;
            vy = 0;
            onGround = true;

        }
        else
        {
            onGround = false;
        }           
    }

    private function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
        {
            vx = -5;
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 5;
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
        {
            if(onGround == true)
            {
                vy = -5;
                trace("My people need me!");
            }
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            //vy = 5;
            return;
        }
    }

    private function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
        {
            vx = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
        {
            //vy = 0;
            return;
        }
    }

    private function removeStageHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeStageHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
    }
}
```

package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

```
public class Collision
{
    static public var collisionSide:String = ""; 

    public function Collision()
    {
    }
    static public function block(r1:Sprite, r2:Sprite):Boolean
    {
        var isBlocked:Boolean;
        //Calculate the distance vector
        var vx:Number 
            = (r1.x + (r1.width / 2)) 
            - (r2.x + (r2.width / 2));

        var vy:Number 
            = (r1.y + (r1.height / 2)) 
            - (r2.y + (r2.height / 2));

        //Check whether vx 
        //is less than the combined half widths
        if(Math.abs(vx) < r1.width / 2 + r2.width / 2)
        {
            //A collision might be occurring! Check 
            //whether vy is less than the combined half heights
            if(Math.abs(vy) < r1.height / 2 + r2.height / 2)
            {
                //A collision has ocurred! This is good!

                //Find out the size of the overlap on both the X and Y axes
                var overlap_X:Number 
                = r1.width / 2 
                    + r2.width / 2 
                    - Math.abs(vx);

                var overlap_Y:Number 
                = r1.height / 2 
                    + r2.height / 2 
                    - Math.abs(vy);

                //The collision has occurred on the axis with the
                //*smallest* amount of overlap. Let's figure out which
                //axis that is

                if(overlap_X >=  overlap_Y)
                {
                    //The collision is happening on the X axis
                    //But on which side? _v0's vy can tell us 
                    if(vy > 0)
                    {
                        collisionSide = "Top";

                        //Move the rectangle out of the collision
                        r1.y = r1.y + overlap_Y;
                        //r1 is being blocked
                        isBlocked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collisionSide = "Bottom";

                        //Move the rectangle out of the collision
                        r1.y = r1.y - overlap_Y;
                        //r1 is being blocked
                        isBlocked = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //The collision is happening on the Y axis
                    //But on which side? _v0's vx can tell us 
                    if(vx > 0)
                    {
                        collisionSide = "Left";

                        //Move the rectangle out of the collision
                        r1.x = r1.x + overlap_X;
                        //r1 is being blocked
                        isBlocked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collisionSide = "Right"; 

                        //Move the rectangle out of the collision
                        r1.x = r1.x - overlap_X;
                        //r1 is being blocked
                        isBlocked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No collision
                collisionSide = "No collision";
                //r1 is not being blocked
                isBlocked = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No collision
            collisionSide = "No collision";
            //r1 is not being blocked
            isBlocked = false;
        }
        return isBlocked;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to set the bottomlimit, but not hardcode the number 400, correct?

I would do change your createFloor method:

```
private function createFloor(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):void
{
    var floor:Floor = new Floor();
    addChild(floor);
    floor.x = xPos;
    floor.y = yPos;
    floor.height = 16;
    _floor.push(floor);
    floor.visible = false;

    // set bottom limit here
    bottomLimit = yPos;
}
```

... then you wouldnt need to set it to 400.

However, another option is to change your if statement:

```
    if(_mario.y >= Floor(_floor[0]).y)
    {
        _mario.y = Floor(_floor[0]).y;
        vy = 0;
        onGround = true;

    }
    else
    {
        onGround = false;
    }
```

... and then you can get rid of the bottomLimit variable completely
(assuming I understood your code, and that the floor tiles are always going to be at the bottomLimit)

Comment: After adding either one he continues to fall through the floor only to the yPos of the floor, after adjustment of the yPos he doesn't fall through anymore. Now for some reason he refuses to jump until he moves off of the previously stated floor, so in this case after I adjusted it "createFloor(16, 400);" when he moves past line that starts at 16, he will then allow himself to jump.